# GitHub Actions - Mounting Volumes for Docker Containers

Tags: docker, github-actions

I've been getting up-to-speed on using Docker within GitHub Actions, and I keep running across code like this:

```
docker run --rm -t \
            -v "/home/runner":"/home/runner" \
            -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" \
            -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" \
            -v "${{ github.workspace }}":"/github/workspace" \
            ...
```

I'm curious what the motivation for mounting all these volumes is. I get the `/github/workspace` one, to access all of your repository files within the Docker container, but what are these ones for?

- `/home/runner`
- `/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home`
- `/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow`

"What are you talking about, where did you see this?"

- https://github.community/t/self-hosted-runner-cant-mount-workspace-correctly/17242
- In the accepted answer here: [GitHub Action I wrote doesn't have access to repo's files that is calling the action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609618/github-action-i-wrote-doesnt-have-access-to-repos-files-that-is-calling-the-ac)
- https://giters.com/actions/runner/issues/965
- Multiple other locations

And yet, I can find no documentation about why you might want to do this.